# OID for creation date/time (X509 certificate field)

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, x.509

X509 certificates used in PKI{X} have `notBefore` and `notAfter` dates. I'd like to stamp a certificate with a creation stamp, and the stamp is distinct from `notBefore` and `notAfter`.

Is there an OID for a creation date/time?

I looked through X.520 and did not see a similar OID. The description OID is already being used in this particular PKI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing that is recognized and interpreted by TLS clients -- the reason being such a field is entirely irrelevant. There's no action to take based on what such a field would contain, so nothing would have a reason to even read it.

But if you want to record that information for your own bookkeeping, then just embed the information somewhere where it won't break anything. The `nsComment` field is a good example. Or you could create your own OID. There's no harm in that as long as you don't re-use someone else's prefix.